# Apollo fetchMore updates data globally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I have two `TaskList` components that use the same query `GET_TASKS`.

Both use a different `filter` query variable which is passed down to them in props as `queryVars`.

I defined a standard merge function in type policies to merge the incoming and existing data together.

The TaskList component uses

```
const { data, fetchMore } = useQuery<Response, Variables>(GET_TASKS, { variables: queryVars })
```

to retrieve the data.

A `Fetch more` button has `() => fetchMore({ variables: queryVars })` in the `onClick` attribute.

When I click on the `Fetch more` button on the left, the tasks on the right get updated as well, however, without its filter applied, so the data that come with *Assigned to me* filter are also put to the *Assigned by me* task list and vice versa.

The merge function basically rewrites every data object that uses the given query.

How do I tell Apollo to only update the data that is bound to the component where `fetchMore` is defined?

[image: task lists]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to add filter to the keyArgs property. This should create different cache results based on the filter.

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        tasks: {
          keyArgs: ["filter"],
          merge(existing, incoming, { args: { offset = 0 }}) {
            //Custom merge
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```